# Elasticsearch / Kibana: Application-side joins

Tags: join, elasticsearch, kibana

is it possible with Kibana (preferably the shining new version 4 beta) to perform application-side joins?

I know that ES / Kibana is not built to replace relational- databases and it is normally a better idea to denormalize my data. In this use-case however, this is not the best approach since index-size is exploding and performance is dropping:

I'm indexing billions of documents containing session information of network flows like this: source ip, source port, destination ip, destination port, timestamp.

Now I also want to collect additional information for each ip address, such as geolocation, asn, reverse dns etc. Adding this information to every single session document makes the whole database unmanageable: There are millions of documents with the same ip addresses and the redundancy of adding the same additional information to all these documents leads to a massive bloat and an unresponsive user-experience even on a cluster with hundreds of gigabytes of ram.

Instead I would like to create a separate index containing only unique ip addresses and the metadata that I have collected to each one of them.

**The question is:** How can I still analyze my data using kibana? For each document returned by the query, kibana should perform a lookup in the ip-index and "virtually enrich" each ip address with this information. Something like adding virtual fields so the structure would look like this (on the fly):

source ip, source port, *source country, source asn, source fqdn*

I'm aware that this would come at the cost of multiple queries.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using doc_values for your non analyzed field cache? Personally, before I would even attempt to normalize my data, I'd try switching to doc_values to see if that helped. You might also want to look int global ordinals (Eg https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/fielddata-formats.html) but with high cardinality data I actually don't think that would be a very good idea....

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is such thing, but maybe that you could play around with the filters :

1. You create nice and simple data visualisations that filter on
   different types and display only one simple data.
2. You put these different visualizations in a dashboard in order to display all the data associated with a type of join.
3. You use the filters as your join key and use the full dashboard,
   composed of different panels, to get insights of specific join keys
   (ips in your case, or sessions)

You need to create 1 dashboard for every type of join that you want to make.

Note that you will need to harmonize the names and mappings of the fields in your different documents!

Keep us updated, that's an interesting problematic, I would like to now how it turns out with so many documents.